# i am getting 'cb' argument error when i run the code

Tags: node.js

I wrote this code:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var data = {
    name:'Bob'
}
```

and I get this error:

```
fs.writeFile('data.json',data) "the 'cb' argument must be of type function. Received undefined"
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and make sure to **ask a question**. Do not just post some code and an error message. This is not a help desk. Before posting, [please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to understand the problem, by reading the error message and by [using a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=node.js+fs.writefile).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're using [the asynchronous callback-style `fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilefile-data-options-callback) API without a callback (`cb` for short).

In addition, you're not encoding your data to JSON before attempting to write it, so that too would fail.

Either:

- use [`fs.writeFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilesyncfile-data-options) for synchronous file writing:

  ```
  fs.writeFileSync("data.json", JSON.stringify(data));
  ```
- pass in a callback (that can be anything, but it needs to be there):

  ```
  fs.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify(data), (err) => err && console.error(err));
  ```
- [use `fs/promises`'s promise-based asynchronous API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromiseswritefilefile-data-options):

  ```
  var fsp = require('fs/promises');
  await fsp.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify(data));
  ```